# Return a dict from map function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

newb here, hello! I'm using map() function to iterate a list of Tickers (strings) through OHLCV download function with multiprocessing. As a result, I receive a list of dataframes.

```
All_coins_history = Shark_pool.map(refractor_get_history, Tickers)
```

As my dataframes with history have just `Dataframe[["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]]` format, there is no way for me to know which data from All_coins_history list is for which Ticker. What is the clean way to create, for example, a dictionary instead of list, where each dataframe would have its Ticker as a key?

Comment: Please add some example input and output data, as well as more code to clarify your question (e.g. what are `Shark_pool`, `refactor_get_history`, and `Tickers`?).  Ideally your question should contain a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair up the ticker symbols with the result of the mapping, then call `dict()` to create the dictionary.

```
all_coins_history = dict(zip(Tickers, Shark_pool.map(refractor_get_history, Tickers)))
```